# Adding custom text when exporting data to excel from asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, export-to-excel

My asp.net application exports gridview data to an excel file. However, I also need to input Customer information before the gridview values are displayed.

```
gvCustomerPayment.DataSource = ViewState["data"];
gvCustomerPayment.AllowPaging = false;
gvCustomerPayment.DataBind();

gvCustomerPayment.RenderControl(hw);
gvCustomerPayment.Rows[2].Cells[0].Text = Convert.ToString("Customer Name: " + dr["FirstName"] + dr["LastName"]);
```

The gridview data is displayed perfectly fine. The last line in my code block **Convert.ToString("Customer Name:");** needs to be in cell A2 (see section in red in image below).

[image]

I have searched S/O & google, but nothing helpful.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Question... do you have Auto Generate Field Names set to false.. also when altering Databound items have you looked at creating BindingList<string> the reason I ask is because once DataBind() I am pretty sure that you can't alter perhaps you may want to create a BindingList<string> and assign the values from the ViewState["data"] to the BindingList<string> and make the .DataSource = BindingList<string>

Comment: You are changing the cell value AFTER you have rendered the control using the HtmWriter. You need to do it before you call RenderControl

Comment: @Icarus if I change the cell value before RenderControl, it shows up as overwriting a value within the gridview.

Comment: @Dotnetrookie sorry, I thought that's what you wanted... In that case, set the Caption of the Gridview to be the Customer name. If all you need is to put a title to the exported file, that should do it. gv.Caption="Customer ABC"

Comment: @Icarus have a look at the screenshot. What I am looking for is how to write the section highlighted in red... "Customer Name: Michael K. Smith" in the excel file, above the gridview values. And then on the line below, I want to show "Address : 123 Solar Street" and so on.

Comment: Have you tried EPPlus available on codeplex? Very easy to work with. http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Creating-an-Excel-Workbook-3d4a7776

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two ways.

1. You can use an excel template with macro code.
   But this way is annoying.
2. You can use NPOI library to write some values to specified cells.
   NPOI is very easy to use.
   Here is the link: http://npoi.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Put the controls in a div where all the details to be exported. Export the div to excel.

Let the aspx file be like this

```
  <div id="divExport" runat="server">
    <div id="dvheads" runat="server">
        <b>
          <label id="lblCustomerName" runat="server"></label><br /><br />
          <label id="lblAddress" runat="server"></label><br /><br />
          <label id="lblPin" runat="server"></label>
            </b>
    </div>
        <br />

        <asp:GridView ID="GVLoans" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" HorizontalAlign="left" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>Sl No</HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblSRNO" runat="server" 
                Text='<%#Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

        <br />
        </div>
```

In .cs file  the code for export will be like this

```
 protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("content-isposition",attachment;filename=testExport.xls");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
    System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
    divExport.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
    Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
    Response.End();
 }
```